# Proving that $ \frac{S_n}{n} \to -1$ almost surely

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be independent RVs such that
>   $$ X_n =   \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
>       n^2 - 1 &\text{ with probability $n^{-2}$}; \\
>       -1    &\text{ with probability $1 - n^{-2}$}. \\
> \end{array} 
> \right. $$
>   Prove that $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = 0$, $\forall n$, but that if $S_n = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots X_n$, then
>   $$ \frac{S_n}{n} \to -1, \qquad \text{a.s.}.$$

MY ATTEMPT.

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that
$$ \mathbb{E}[X_n] = (n^2 - 1)(n^{-2}) + (-1)(1 - n^{-2}) =  1 - n^{-2} - 1 + n^{-2} = 0. $$
Thus, $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = 0$, for each $n$. (Easy.)

We now need to show that
$$ \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{S_n}{n} \to -1 \right) = 1. $$
Let's simplify notation by letting $Y_n = S_n / n$, for each $n$. Then we need to show that
$$ \mathbb{P}\left( \lim_{n \to \infty}Y_n = -1 \right) = 1; $$
or, equivalently,
$$ \mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\omega \in \Omega : \lim_{n \to \infty} Y_n(\omega) = -1\right\} \right) = 1 .$$
Well, the event
$$ E = \left\{\omega \in \Omega : \lim_{n \to \infty} Y_n(\omega) = -1\right\} $$
belongs to the tail $\sigma$-algebra for the sequence $\{X_n\}$. So, by Kolgomorov's 0-1 Law, $\mathbb{P}(E) \in \{0,1\}$. It will therefore be sufficient to show that $\mathbb{P}(E) > 0$. So, let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and, for each $n$, define the event
$$E_n = \{\omega \in \Omega : |Y_n(\omega) + 1| < \epsilon\}. $$
Note that, for each $n$,
$$\mathbb{P}(E_n) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(E^c) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega : |Y_n(\omega) + 1| \ge \epsilon\}).$$
For each $n$, define $Z_n = |Y_n + 1|$. Then each $Z_n$ is a nonnegative random variable. So, by Markov's Inequality
$$\mathbb{P}(Z_n \ge \epsilon) \le \frac{\mathbb{E}[Z_n]}{\epsilon}.$$
Now, we note that, since $X_n \ge -1$, for each $n$, it follows that $Y_n + 1 \ge 0$, for each $n$; and so $Z_n = Y_n + 1$. Thus,
$$ \mathbb{E}[Z_n] = \mathbb{E}[Y_n + 1] = \mathbb{E}[Y_n] + 1, $$
where
$$\mathbb{E}[Y_n] = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_n\right] = \frac{1}{n}(\mathbb{E}[X_1] + \mathbb{E}[X_2] + \cdots \mathbb{E}[X_n]) = 0. $$
So, independent of $n$
$$\mathbb{P}(Z_n \ge \epsilon) \le \frac{1}{\epsilon} \implies 1-\mathbb{P}(Z_n \ge \epsilon) \ge 1 - \frac{1}{\epsilon} \implies \mathbb{P}(E_n) \ge 1 - \frac{1}{\epsilon}.$$
This simply says that $\mathbb{P}(E_n)$ is greater than a negative number, which is of course of no use.

This is the best I could do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much simpler if you use Borel-Cantelli Lemma. Since $\sum_n P(X_n=n^{2}-1)<\infty$ it follows that $X_n=-1$ for all suffciciently large values of $n$, with probability $1$. This implies that $\frac {S_n} n \to -1$ with probability $1$.